# How to extract substring after particular word in python?

Tags: python, selenium, substring, indexof

I have developed code in Java for a small project which would fetch some data from Google Result page.

From the below Paragraph, I have to extract "Announced Sep 2019" alone.

OnePlus 7T Android smartphone. Announced Sep 2019. Features 6.55″ Fluid AMOLED display, Snapdragon 855+ chipset, 3800 mAh battery, 256 GB storage, ...

```
String ReleaseDate = sr1.substring(sr1.indexOf("Announced"),sr1.indexOf("Announced")+18);
```

Using Java I have achieved the same by the above coding. Now the requirement is for python coding. Could somebody help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ReleaseData = sr1[sr1.index("Announced"):sr1.index("Announced")+18]
```

Comment: Python uses something called splicing to get substrings.